# Creating an uninitialized array of items which have default constructors?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, c++14, default-constructor

Given a class `Foo` which has some value-initializing default constructor:

```
class Foo {
private:
    uint32_t x;

public:
    constexpr Foo()
        : x { 3 }
    {}
    // ... and some other constructors
};
```

I need to allocate an array of these `Foo`'s. I don't want the array's elements' default constructors to run, because later I'm going to initialize each element explicitly anyway. Something like this:

```
Foo foos[20000];

for (int i = 0; i < 20000; ++i) {
    foos[i] = init(i);
}
```

Is there a way to obtain such an uninitialized array of `Foo`'s given that we're not allowed to change the default constructor of `Foo` into a non-initializing one?

By the way, this is how you'd create an uninitialized array in D:

```
Foo[20000] foos = void;
```

...and here's the same in Rust:

```
let mut foos: [Foo; 20000] = unsafe { std::mem::uninitialized() };
```

Comment: `char arr[20000 * sizeof(Foo)]; auto foos = reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(arr);`?

Comment: @zch: Beware of alignment.

Comment: Have you profiled that the default constructor calls caused a performance problem? (I assume that's why you're interested in this)

Comment: @zch that violates strict aliasing, unfortunately

Comment: @NeilKirk: No, I don't really have a specific issue with this at hand. I'm just interested in learning the way to program these kinds of things without unnecessary overhead (it's C++ afterall:).

Comment: Actually, cppreference has an example that deals with similar problem http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage

Comment: @MattMcNabb, `char` doesn't have strict aliasing problems. However, it might need placement `new`.

Comment: @zch: I'm really not sure, but I think that your example can cause undefined behaviour due to some C++ rules that are referred to as "strict aliasing".

Comment: @zch `char` may be used to alias other types, but other type may not be used to alias `char`

Comment: @kmky C++ has encapsulation; if you define your class so that the only way of constructing it is to initialize a value to 3, then there is no other way to construct it. (Sounds tautological because it is!).   You can allocate memory that does not yet contain objects (`vector::reserve` works this way).

Comment: @MattMcNabb. Okay, than I think placement `new` deals with it. Then your program does not "attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue" at all until object of appropriate type is constructed with `new`. That's basically what any use of `std::aligned_storage` would do.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: To encapsulate it like that was not my intention. I just didn't write any other constructors because I didn't think that they mattered. By all means, the `Foo` class could have for example the following non-initializing non-default constructor: `Foo(Uninitialized) {}` and there would be a helper enum to call that: `enum Uninitialized { uninit };`. I don't see how this kind of relaxation of encapsulation would help to solve my issue.

Comment: Re zch's suggestion - I agree aliasing problems could kick in if the memory's changed via `char*`s into `arr` *and* via `Foo*` such as `foos` - if only that latter is used to init/access/modify the memory, is there still a potential problem?  I'd hazard not....

Comment: @MattMcNabb: `std::array` doesn't have constructors.

Comment: @TonyD aliasing talks about *accessing* which includes both reads and writes. See 3.10/10.  An array of unsigned char is an object whose dynamic type is "array of unsigned char" .

Comment: @kmky d'oh. It is a slight language weakness that C-style arrays cannot be given an initializer to apply to all elements.  You could write `Foo foos[20000] = { uninit, uninit, uninit, uninit, `etc.  - either copy-pasting or using another program to generate the source for you.   Another option would be to derive from `Foo` and provide a default constructor that does what you want; and then have your array of the derived class (which can slice down to `Foo` if required).

Comment: @zch: I think that the example in the [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) you provided does exactly what I want to do. It allocates on the stack without initializing and then does emplace to initialize elements. Thanks.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: thanks for the ref to 3.10/10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this answers the question at hand more accurately?

```
#include <type_traits>

class Foo {
private:
    uint32_t x;

public:
    constexpr Foo()
        : x { 3 }
    {}

    constexpr Foo(uint32_t n)
        : x { n * n }
    {}
};

    // ...and then in some function:

    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Foo), alignof(Foo)>::type foos[20000];

    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; ++i) {
        new (foos + i) Foo(i);
    }
```

The drawback seems to be that you can use only a constructor to initialize those elements, and not a free function or anything else.

Question: Can I then access those `Foo`'s like this:

```
    Foo* ptr = reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(foos);
    ptr[50] = Foo();
```

Comment: Objects can only be constructed via their constructor, it's not a "drawback" so much as "working as intended".   Your access code seems correct, so long as you do it after the construction loop of course.

Answer (score 2):

If you using `C++11`, you can use `std::vector` and `emplace_back()`

```
vector<Foo> foos;
for(int i = 0; i < 20000; ++i)
    foos.emplace_back( /* arguments here */);
```

Comment: This works but if the purpose of using a C-style array and avoiding the use of default constructors was performance (why else?) using a vector may be slower.

Comment: @NeilKirk profile before assuming...    The vector could initially `reserve(20000);` to avoid unnecessary allocations. Anyway I don't see a better option than this.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I agree with you, however given the context of the question, I assumed he was looking for micro-optimizations given some profiling  already. Also is a compiler allowed to do that by the standard?

Comment: vector with reserve should be optimal. it grabs raw bytes using default allocator and constructs elements with placement-new as required.

Comment: The compiler can do anything that doesnt change the programs' observable behaviour, although in my experiecne they wouldn't do the `reserve` without you specifically coding it

Comment: What if I'd like to allocate the array on stack instead of heap. Is it possible to do the same kind of magic that `std::vector` does under the hood (with `reserve` and `emplace_back`) with a stack-allocated blob of uninitialized memory?

Comment: @MattMcNabb That's what I'm saying. I've never noticed my compiler to reserve without me telling it to.

Comment: @kmky You only need to use the stack if you have a performance issue, but you said that wasn't the case.

Comment: @NeilKirk: I don't have any specific issue at hand. My goal is to learn to do this just in case I ever encounter a performance issue which could be alleviated by not initializing each element twice.

Comment: @kmky I know it's not perfect and it may bug you, but I've never encountered a performance problem related to default constructors in an array that set an integer. I would not worry about this too much :)

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking for is `std::get_temporary_buffer`:

```
int main()
{
  size_t n = 20000;
  auto buf = std::get_temporary_buffer<Foo>(n);
  if (buf.second<n) {
    std::cerr << "Couldn't allocate enough memory\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // ...

  std::raw_storage_iterator<Foo*,Foo> iter(buf.first);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    *iter++ = Foo();
  }

  // ...

  std::return_temporary_buffer(buf.first);
}
```

Comment: It's implementation-defined just how efficient those temporary buffers are. I checked on one of the Visual Studios and it just secretly called new.

Comment: Interesting, but deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20.